# Applying a fill to multiple layers using Option/CMD + Delete in Photoshop CS6

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, cs6

Similar to what can be done in Illustrator is there a way to apply one fill to multiple selected layers with or without the hotkey, Option/CMD + Delete vs. applying the fill to each individually?

Answer (score 1):

You really can't without scripting, or even an action to fill the layer with the set foreground/background color.

If I need multiple layers filled with the same color, I generally fill one via <kbd>Command/CTRL</kbd> / <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd>, then use <kbd>Command/CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>j</kbd> to simply duplicate that layer.

Answer (score 0):

smart objects.
Create smart objects, clip them to the layers you want to change, and swap the original.